# Button click on viewnavigator in flex 4 Mobile?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5

ViewNavigator is basically used for navigating around different views, but is there a easier way to just restrict switching to any view and do some operation instead?

eg: I am viewing a product manual or help doc, and without going into any view i'd like to call customer care by clicking on a button in viewnavigator

code

```
<s:ViewNavigator id="navigatorHome" width="100%" height="100%"  
                 elementAdd="viewAdded(event)" elementRemove="viewRemoved(event)" 
                 icon="{Images.iconHome64}" firstView="{HomeView}">

            <s:navigationContent>
                <s:Button icon="{iconBack}" click="{navigatorHome.activeView.navigator.popView()}"/>
            </s:navigationContent>              
</s:ViewNavigator>
<s:ViewNavigator id="navigatorPhone" width="100%" height="100%" 
                 elementAdd="viewAdded(event)" elementRemove="viewRemoved(event)" 
                 icon="{iconPhone}" >
</s:ViewNavigator>
<s:ViewNavigator id="navigatorAlert" width="100%" height="100%" 
                 elementAdd="viewAdded(event)" elementRemove="viewRemoved(event)" 
                 icon="{iconAlerts}" firstView="{AlertView}">
</s:ViewNavigator>
<s:ViewNavigator id="navigatorSettings" width="100%" height="100%" 
                 elementAdd="viewAdded(event)" elementRemove="viewRemoved(event)" 
                 icon="{iconSettings}" firstView="{SettingsView}">
            <s:navigationContent>
                <s:Button icon="{iconBack}" click="{navigatorSettings.activeView.navigator.popView()}"/>
            </s:navigationContent>
</s:ViewNavigator>
```

So here `navigatorPhone` should not open any view, but instead call some function, Is there a way?

**Update**

I saw it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html) that there is a `Removing event` so I got this

```
private function removing(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
{
    trace("Inside removing event: "+event.currentTarget.name+", "+communicateViewCalled+", "+navigatorHome.activeView.name);
    //event.preventDefault();
}
```

So here if anyhow I get to know the clicked view, it will do the trick. any help?

trace output by default I am on `HomeView` and clicked `CommunicateView`

> > Inside removing event: HomeView, false, HomeView

Answer (score 0):

Either you can add the functionality to your view, or you need to write a proper eventListener for you button to check the type of the current view and determine that way, what to do.

Comment: [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html) I saw there is a `removing` event which I can use, so is there a way that I can get the name of clicked view name here? under `removing` event I get which view is currently about to remove, but if I also get to know which is the view that got clicked will do the trick